# Creating a Woocommerce product item when publishing a post

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When publishing a Wordpress post at backend, I would like a pdf version of the post to be created automatically (or at the click of a button) and paralely a Woocommerce digital product item of it (always with the same product parameters, e.g. the same price) also be created. How can this be accomplished?

I tried with some pdf generator plugins, and some post duplicator ones then I changed the post_type to product... but it needs manual process steps. Any idea for automation? For example any code into the functions.php ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need pdf lib for the job such as FPDF. then use new_to_publish , draft_to_publish, pending_to_publish actions to execute your pdf creation. From what you are trying to achieve you need on each action to check if the post type is product and its digital then assign the created file to it. I would recommend to also include update_post action in case you change something in the product to regenerate the pdf file too if needed